# Web-Push уведомления

Tags: javascript, push-уведомления

Ребят кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.

Нужно сделать push нотификации в браузере (Желательно без бэкенда). 
Нашел гайды от гугла (все равно не понятно) и упоминания о либе web-push.

Подскажите годные гайды по этой теме, может уроки какие.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/321924/

Comment: А куда отправлять сообщения?

Comment: @RomanC тут же на клиент. По сути сервак не нужен. Нужно показывать локально уведомление.

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy тоже нашел это. Но есть одно но. Мне не нужен сервак как таковой. Мне нужно отправлять пуши локально на сайте.

Comment: @Tsyklop, локально это не пуши, это [`Notification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: @Grundy бог просто. Подскажи. а как с этим делом обстоит в сафари?

Comment: Базовая поддержка вроде есть

Comment: @Grundy оформите в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push`-уведомления делаются *сервером*, поэтому без бэкенда не обойтись.

Однако есть [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/notification) для показа сообщений

Например:

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Проверка поддержки браузером уведомлений
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Проверка разрешения на отправку уведомлений
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // Если разрешено, то создаем уведомление
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // В противном случае, запрашиваем разрешение
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // Если пользователь разрешил, то создаем уведомление 
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // В конечном счете, если пользователь отказался от получения 
  // уведомлений, то стоит уважать его выбор и не беспокоить его 
  // по этому поводу.
}
```